# ionic cordova platform add android Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

when i run

> ionic cordova platform add android

Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2

Adding android project...

Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: io.ionic.starter
        Name: ionicFirebase
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-25
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.2.3

> **Error:** Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

i am try to rm android i found platform array still on config.xml and when i run

> ionic cordove resource

√ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!

[ERROR] No platforms detected. Please run: ionic cordova platform add

and whan i run a gain

> ionic cordova platform add android

say same thing error in path !!

**this is my ionic info**

> ionic info

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

**global packages:**

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

**local packages:**

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
{{{{{Cordova Platforms  : none}}}}
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

**System:**

```
Node : v6.16.0
npm  : 4.6.1
OS   : Windows 10
```

**Misc:**

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove android platform through command like

**ionic cordova platform rm android**

and then try to add it again by

**ionic cordova platform add android**

Lastly if Its not done then once uninstall npm and install it again to higher version(5.6.0).

Comment: i am try rm android and download again same thing error can'T find path i will try update npm

Comment: same error can't find path after update npm to 5.6.0 and cordova 8.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Th error occurs because the image icon is missing so try the following command after adding the platform by navigating into the project folder

```
ionic cordova resources
```

> The `ionic cordova resources` command generates the different sized
>   image for icon and splash screen

Comment: when i try run ionic cordova resources √ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
[ERROR] No platforms detected. Please run: ionic cordova platform add

Comment: i do that but when add android platform >ionic cordova add platform get error can't find path .... after this i try to run ionic cordove resources √ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done! [ERROR] No platforms detected. Please run: ionic cordova platform add

Comment: `No platforms detected` means the platform is not installed. Make sure you enter the correct command for installing android platform

Comment: when i run ionic cordova platform ls i am found android 6.2.3 in install platform